# issue trying view all appointments between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hello. I have a problem with my code below, but can't see any issues with it.

I am trying to get all of the appointments from the appointments table, within the dates input by the user and display them in a table. I am getting a Syntax error.

My mysql query is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointment 
    WHERE Appointment_Date BETWEEN $fromDate AND $toDate 
    AND Practice_ID = '$prac' ORDER by Appointment_Time");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: my while loop looks a little like this, with a few more statements:

{   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Appointment_No'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Appointment_Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Appointment_Time'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>".$pid."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

Answer (score 0):

date are enclosed with single quotes,

```
$result = mysql_query("
        SELECT  * 
        FROM   appointment 
        WHERE  Appointment_Date BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' 
               AND Practice_ID = '$prac' 
        ORDER  BY Appointment_Time");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: hmm thanks for your answer but it still doesn't seem to be working after I have enclosed the date in single quotes

Comment: how about `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $row["Appointment_Date"]; ..... }`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket here:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // << 2 brackets needed at the end
```

And instead of semicolon you need a proper while loop.

```
while(...)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks I've got the page to load at least now due to missing bracket. My while loop statement is too many characters long to post!

Comment: I suggest finding where your server has it's php error logs. You then will be able to see the exact error reasons. I would say something like "unexpected semicolon" and the error line, which is a clear pointer on where is the problem.